# Use variable from Main method in another method

Tags: c#, variables, methods, program-entry-point

I am currently working on an assignment and just wanted a little help with something. For my code I have to find the lowest and highest value from an array of values, then add together the those which are not the highest or lowest (e.g, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 --- I would add 2+3+4)

So I though the best way would be to iterate through the array and record the where the highest/lowest values are stored. This is where I a problem, the array is stored in the Main method, and I haven't found a way to access it in another method. My code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Scoring {
class Program {   
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] scores = { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6 };

        find_Low();

        ExitProgram();
    }

    static int find_Low() {
        int low = int.MaxValue;
        int low_index = -1;


        foreach (int i in scores) {

            if (scores[i] < low) {
                low = scores[i];
                low_index = i;

            }                
        }

        Console.WriteLine(low);
        Console.WriteLine(low_index);
        return low;  
    }

    static void ExitProgram() {
        Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit program: ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }//end ExitProgram
}
```

}

The error I get is "the name 'scores' does not exist in the current context. Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: There are at least three coding styles mixed in this program. Decide on one style (hint: MS style is great for C#, because all libraries use it) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the array as a parameter to the function:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] scores = { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6 };
        Console.WriteLine(resoult(scores));
    }

    static int resoult(int[] pScores)
    {
        return pScores.Sum() - pScores.Max() - pScores.Min();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had roughly the same idea of solving the problem, just didn't know how to use the variable in the new method. Just one last question, why have your renamed scores to pScores in the method declaration? would it not work without renaming it? thanks

Comment: It's just a naming convention. They can both share the same name "scores".

Comment: @user3496101 If you find an answer helped you. Choose it as answer to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

To keep it as simple as possible, change your program like this

```
class Program {

    static int[] scores = { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6 };

    static void Main(string[] args) { ...}
}
```

Comment: The scores variable must be static if you want to acces it from static method. Also it's almost always better to use parameters than static fields.

Comment: Right, forgot to add the static. Sure parameters are better, but I was aiming for the simplest fix to his problem, to avoid more confusion ...

Answer (score 1):

Pass your array as parameter:

```
static int find_Low(int[] scores) { 
     //your code
    }
```

In MainMethod:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int[] scores = { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6 };

    find_Low(scores);    //pass array

    ExitProgram();
}
```